# What did Darren Cross mean with "Word travels fast"

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015, language-explanation

In the recent Ant-man movie,

> when Dr. Pym has been invited to Pym Tech and Darren is about to sell the suit to Hydra, it is revealed that Cross knew about their plan to steal the Yellowjacket. We hear Darren say, "It's not easy to successfully infiltrate an Avengers facility.  Thankfully, **word travels fast**." (emphasis mine)

How did Darren know this and were the viewers supposed to "get it"? Is there a leak?

Comment: If someone can find the exact wording of the dialogue, much appreciated.

Comment: Scott didn't steal anything from SHIELD.  He went to an old Stark warehouse (now repurposed into something else *cough*) to steal something.  I don't recall Cross mentioning knowing about that theft though, nor is him knowing about it necessary to be aware of Pym's scheme.

Comment: Well, that Stark warehouse is on the grounds of the new Avengers campus facility. I assumed that since Shield knew there'd been an incident and something may have been stolen, then HYDRA ( Since it's interwoven into SHIELD still ) would know.

Comment: I do recall Cross saying that. However after antman I don't know if anything new in the MCU has been released (including the tv shows). We'll just have to wait and see.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I do think @Covertwalrus is on to something..

Comment: He went there to steal a Macguffin.

Comment: Is HYRDA still interwoven into SHIELD? I haven't kept up on the show but this is definitely post CA2 so I thought they'd be separate at this point.

Comment: There you go, I added the relevant quote.

Comment: At this point it isn't very clear. All I can assume is.... Hail HYDRA!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"It's not easy to successfully infiltrate an Avengers facility. Thankfully, word travels fast." In the Winter Soldier-Hydra had spies and leaders all over the place-including Shield. I couldn't remember if those events were before Ant-Man or after, but in EITHER case-Cross is planning on selling the suit to Hydra's operatives. They would no doubt have told Cross that someone small broke into Shield, and that he should watch himself. I would even go so far as to say that's how he knew to spring the trap when everyone showed up to steal the suit, as there wasn't much else to suggest corporate espionage up to that point.

Answer (score 1):

Words travel fast is an [idiom](https://ludwig.guru/s/word+travels+fast#:%7E:text=%27word%20travels%20fast%27%20is%20correct,%2D%20word%20travels%20fast!%22.):

> You can use this phrase in formal and informal contexts, to describe someone's news or opinion spreading quickly. For example, you could say, "I heard about the protests the day after they began - word travels fast!".

So Darren simply means the news of Scott's infiltration to the Avengers facility has spread quickly.